# Prove that $\forall$ n $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ $7^n\equiv 1 \bmod{20}$ iff $n=4k$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that $\forall$ n $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ 
$7^n\equiv 1 \bmod{20}$ iff  $n=4k$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [MSE quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. Making these improvements will attract more appropriate answers and make the question more valuable for future MSE visitors.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$7\equiv7, \ 7^2\equiv9, \ 7^3\equiv3, \ 7^4\equiv1, 7^5\equiv7 \ldots \pmod{20}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint for the other direction: $n=4k$ implies $7^n=7^{4k}=(7^4)^k$

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove the converse of the statement: *If* $7^{n} \equiv 1 \bmod 20$*, then* $n = 4k$.

Assume $7^{n} \equiv 1 \bmod 20$.  With P..'s response, you should see that for every power n divisible by 4, $7^{n} \equiv 1 \bmod 20$.  We can use Euler's Theorem and Chinese Remainder Theorem to verify this.  Note that 20 is the composite number, which is factored to $4 \times 5$, and $gcd(4,5) = 1$.  By Euler's theorem, we can write the following equivalences:

$7^{2} \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, which is equivalent to $7^{4} \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ by squaring both sides.

$7^{4} \equiv 1 \bmod 5$

So by Chinese Remainder Theorem $7^{4} \equiv 1 \bmod 20$.  But $7$ to any exponent divisible by $4$ gives $1 \bmod 20$.  Thus $n = 4k$.

Proving the statement another way is straightforward.  Observe that if $n = 4k$:

$7^{n} = 7^{4k} = (7^{4})^{k} = 1^{k} = 1$ for any positive integer $k$.

Thus, $7^{n} \equiv 1 \bmod 20$.